# QString and OpenCV cv.namedWindow()

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qstring, qtcore

A Qt 4.8.1 C++ console application using OpenCV 2.4.2 is reading and displaying USB webcam images via the [highgui](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow) module.
It creates a window for displaying an image (using Qt internally itself I think) using the function

```
void namedWindow(const string& winname, int flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE )
```

However, I am missing how to convert the string to a format that does not end up as unreadable / scrambled / garbage characters. This is what I have tried:

```
QString windowname = "My View";
namedWindow( windowname.toStdString() );
```

How can the QString be converted to something the function displays correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
QString windowname = "My View";
namedWindow( windowname.toStdString().c_str(), CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
```

Comment: namedWindow declared as: namedWindow(const string& winname, int flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); you trying to put char* instead string, it shouldn't work. But I'm not downvote you for this :) .

Comment: It has another overload, and it does work, I use it all the time, so you shouldn't be downvoting anyway :)